# how to repeatedly append a string?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, append, repeat

Hello I am a new programmer so I dont know the computer sciency, pythonic way of saying it.. But what I am looking for is maybe a method or a loop function that is able to append to a dictionary.

What I have tried is a for loop function where I say

```
'K' = 0 + 1
```

and each time the func loops it adds a 1 till 10 then it stops... because I want the word to be repeated only 10 times... but now I am stuck, how do I get the word to be repeated 10 times.

Because remember this is a dictionary example:

```
{Words:['hi', 'bye', 'goodbye']}
```

I want each word to be repeated 10 times and appended to the a dictionary.

Sorry if my question seems like its just asking u to do this problem for me.

**EDIT:**

input:

```
    {Words:['hi', 'bye', 'goodbye']}
```

output:

```
     {Words:['hi','hi','hi','hi','hi','hi','hi','hi','hi','hi', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'goodbye','goodbye','goodbye','goodbye','goodbye','goodbye','goodbye','goodbye','goodbye','goodbye']}
```

as you can see each word is now repeated 10 times in the new dictionary.

Comment: The question itself is not clear. Please explain with sample input and output.

Comment: okay let me update the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
num, mydict = 10, {"Words":['hi', 'bye', 'goodbye']}
print {k: [i for i in v for j in range(num)] for k, v in mydict.items()}
```

**Output**

```
{'Words': ['hi', 'hi', 'hi', 'hi', 'hi', 'hi', 'hi', 'hi', 'hi', 'hi', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'goodbye', 'goodbye', 'goodbye', 'goodbye', 'goodbye', 'goodbye', 'goodbye', 'goodbye', 'goodbye', 'goodbye']}
```

Comment: Hey really appreciate you taking out the time and helping me, there seems to be one thing... I am getting error: name 'Words' is not defined

Comment: That's because 'Words' should be a string.

Comment: ahh yess just noticed that

Comment: @thefourtheye will do my friend

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
d = {'Words':['hi', 'bye', 'goodbye']}
new_d = {}
for key in d:
    new_d[key] = []
    for element in d[key]:
        new_d[key] += [element]*10

print new_d
```